# undefined reference to MinFilter and MaxFilter in StereoMatch code

Tags: c++

everyone

Recently, I'm working on stereo vision. And I download the StereoMatch code from middlebury website: http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/code/

I used Ubuntu 11.10 to run this code. After I run this code, I got the following error. There are 3 'undefined reference to ' error. But the code has already included the header file 'MinFilter.h'. And I get confused. Could someone help me? I would appreciate it.

errors:

StcAggregate.o: In function `CStereoMatcher::AggrMin()':
StcAggregate.cpp:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to`void MinFilter(CImageOf&, CImageOf&, int, int)'
StcEvaluate.o: In function `_ZL14PartialShuffle8CImageOfIhERS0_S1_f.constprop.2':
StcEvaluate.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to`void MinFilter(CImageOf&, CImageOf&, int, int)'
StcEvaluate.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `void MaxFilter(CImageOf&, CImageOf&, int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [StereoMatch] Error 1

Comment: you need to link to the relevant libraries.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know what's kind of library do I need to to add.

Comment: Are you trying to build and install the code, or are you trying to use it?

Comment: I want to build and install this code, and then I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from the linker (and/or runtime environment) which cannot find some symbols (i.e. code) which the header files you've included promised to exist. In order for these symbols to be found, you must tell the linker to link against the library (or object file) containing them. This library may have come with the code pre-compiled or may have been made during installation. Have you not got a README file where it is explained how to use (i.e. link and run) the code?

Comment: It seems there is a problem to create the two object files: StcAggregate.o and StcEvaluate.o . So I recreate these two object files by doing these: g++ -Wall -c StcAggregate.cpp and g++ -Wall -c StcEvaluate.cpp. Now it works. Thanks for other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same problem and solved it like this:
Open the Makefile and change the first line from

CPPFLAGS = -O2 -Wall

to

CPPFLAGS = -O -Wall

Then "make clean" and "make", it works for me. So I guess it is because param 
"-O2" does more optimization than expected.